# Placing PayPal buttons inside Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, paypal, vue-component

I'm trying to place PayPal order buttons inside my Vue.js component.

I'm following the [official documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/checkout/set-up-payments/#add-payment-buttons) which basically says to do 3 things:

1. Import the PayPal SDK script
2. Define a `<div>` element where the buttons will be rendered
3. Add some javascript tode to configure callbacks and render the buttons using variable `paypal`

This is how it looks when I do it in a plain HTML file:

```
<!-- 1 -->

<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?&client-id=xxx"></script>

<!-- 2 -->

<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<!-- 3 -->

<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
      return fetch('http://localhost:8081/api/v1/pay-pal/create-order', {
        method: 'POST'
      }).then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
      }).then(function(data) {
        return data.id;
      });
    },
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
      return fetch('http://localhost:8081/api/v1/pay-pal/capture-order/' + data.orderID, {
        method: 'POST'
      }).then(function(res) {
        if (!res.ok) {
          alert('Something went wrong');
        }
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

The above code works find. My problem is how to do this in a Vue.js component.

For step 1, I used the `mounted()` hook like this:

```
mounted() {
    let payPalSdk = document.createElement('script')
    payPalSdk.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?&client-id=xxx')
    document.head.appendChild(payPalSdk)
}
```

Step 2 was easy, I just added the `div` element into the template.

But where should I put the javascript code to do step 3?

I tried placing it in an external js file and loading it in the `mounted()` method like this:

```
mounted() {
    let payPalSdk = document.createElement('script')
    payPalSdk.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?&client-id=xxx')
    document.head.appendChild(payPalSdk)

    let payPalScript = document.createElement('script')
    payPalScript.setAttribute('src', '/js/paypal.js')
    document.head.appendChild(payPalScript)
}
```

paypal.js:

```
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
      return fetch('http://localhost:8081/api/v1/pay-pal/create-order', {
        method: 'POST'
      }).then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
      }).then(function(data) {
        return data.id;
      });
    },
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
      return fetch('http://localhost:8081/api/v1/pay-pal/capture-order/' + data.orderID, {
        method: 'POST'
      }).then(function(res) {
        if (!res.ok) {
          alert('Something went wrong');
        }
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

The buttons do get rendered, but the console shows the following error:

```
buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182 unhandled_error 
{err: "Error: Invalid json: .↵    at XMLHttpRequest.<anon…rrency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true:1182:22901)", timestamp: "1605367583366", referer: "www.sandbox.paypal.com", sdkCorrelationID: "7d650f42fd450", sessionID: "09b33213cd_mtu6mjy6mja", …}
buttonCorrelationID: "72135879fd67d"
buttonSessionID: "473d7ab57f_mtu6mjy6mja"
env: "sandbox"
err: "Error: Invalid json: .↵    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/buttons?style.layout=vertical&style.color=gold&style.shape=rect&style.tagline=false&components.0=buttons&locale.country=US&locale.lang=en&sdkMeta=eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5wYXlwYWwuY29tL3Nkay9qcz8mY2xpZW50LWlkPUFUX1hyMUl3ekZpM2ItRmhFd0RMQ0VndEM2Y2F4MHgwaWR1VF9yeEprQUhycFRlUXpkbHZRRDhKWFUxZmlNQ01vclN3T1hSWWU1eVVPaENBIiwiYXR0cnMiOnsiZGF0YS11aWQiOiJlOGQyMGY4MzBlX210dTZtank2bWphIn19&clientID=xxx&sessionID=09b33213cd_mtu6mjy6mja&buttonSessionID=473d7ab57f_mtu6mjy6mja&enableBNPL=true&env=sandbox&fundingEligibility=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&platform=desktop&flow=purchase&currency=USD&intent=capture&commit=true:1182:22901)"
referer: "www.sandbox.paypal.com"
sdkCorrelationID: "7d650f42fd450"
sessionID: "09b33213cd_mtu6mjy6mja"
timestamp: "1605367583366"
__proto__: Object
y   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
S   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
error   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
setTimeout (async)      
n.reject    @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.dispatch  @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.reject    @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.dispatch  @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.reject    @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.dispatch  @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.reject    @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
load (async)        
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
e   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
ke  @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
Oe  @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
e.try   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
w   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
e.try   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
setTimeout (async)      
w::promiseDebounced @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
G.then.intent   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.dispatch  @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.resolve   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.dispatch  @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.resolve   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.dispatch  @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.resolve   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.dispatch  @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.resolve   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.dispatch  @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.resolve   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.dispatch  @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
n.resolve   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
setInterval (async)     
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
e   @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
anonymous::memoized @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
G.style @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
ht  @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1182
(anonymous) @   buttons?style.layout…re&commit=true:1183
```

I also tried putting the code insode the `mounted()` hook, but that didn't work because variable `paypal` was undefined there.

Comment: @tao that URL actually returns HTML, not JSON. And this is not the problem because it returns the same HTML when I tried it on the working example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from mounted(), see if either using a callback once the PayPal JS is loaded or the client-side createOrder/onApprove make a difference

```
function loadAsync(url, callback) {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('src', url); s.onload = callback;
  document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.firstElementChild);
}

loadAsync('https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD', function() {
  paypal.Buttons({

    // Set up the transaction
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: '0.01'
                }
            }]
        });
    },

    // Finalize the transaction
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            // Show a success message to the buyer
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
        });
    }

  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
});
```

---

As far as the actual client-side approval code to go ahead and pair with your server backend, I recommend the error handling of https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Thanks, I tried it this way but I'm getting the exact same error.

Comment: Something about your vue environment is interfering or preventing XHR requests. Check the Network tab and cross site headers.

Comment: All calls to paypal.com in the network tab return 200. What do you mean by "check cross site headers"?

Comment: If they are 200, what about the response body isn't JSON?

Comment: I don't see any requests that return JSON. Not even in the working example.

Comment: I found out something new: If I open the working HTML find in the browser directly from disk, the code works. But if I place the HTML file into Vuejs public folder and access it via localhost url, then I get the error. I also tried it in production where I use Apache to serve the files and I also got the error. So maybe it has something to do with the referer?

Comment: Not the referrer, the HTTP headers against cross site calls. Or even that the hostname and port are nonstandard.